# how i create panels with custom tag like header, section footer etc..?

Tags: html, user-interface, drupal-7, themes

My design contains custom tags like `<header>`, `<section>` and `<footer>` , how can I create panels with these tags and put them in many nested panels?

My design contains these custom tags :

```
<header>
    <div>
    </div>
</header>
<section>
    <div>
    </div>
</section>
<footer>
    <div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? or give an exaple what you want?

Comment: how to create custom panel but not need the default tag <div> i need the other surrounded tag like <header id="" class=""> ...

Comment: Oh.. you mean: <panel><element class=""></element></panel>?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, If I good understood you can try this way:

In html file:

```
<panel>
  <element>Somethhing written</element>
</panel>
```

in css file:

```
panel { display:block; }
panel element { display:block; background:#fc0; }
```

I hope I understood good. if no - give an example with code, and we will try find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some proposals are:

1) Copy the relative **tpl.php files** from YOUR_MODULES_PATH/panels/plugins/layouts/CURRENT_LAYOUT into your theme folder and override it as you prefer. These tpl.php files are responsive for the wrapping tags.

See a similar question: [Drupal - dynamically add class to wrapping div based on panel pane content node type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114853/drupal-dynamically-add-class-to-wrapping-div-based-on-panel-pane-content-node/18131659)

2) Use the **[Panels Extra Styles](https://drupal.org/project/panels_extra_styles)** module.